# Can't deploy a project: "Error 114 The following system error occurred: 0 0"

Tags: sql-server, bids

I'm using BIDS 9.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2, I'm trying to deploy a project and all I get is this message:

> "Error 114 The following system error occurred:        0   0"

Comment: Anything in your Windows event logs? If not (well, either way), you're going to have to give us more information that that

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the problem, there were some users in several roles that didn't belong anymore to the users directory. I deleted them from their roles and everything worked.